# What is the pCrawl variable referring to in Trie code?

Tags: naming-conventions, trie, variable-names

Various sites [like this one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/) use a `pCrawl` variable to keep track of where a pointer is in the Trie data structure. I can see why the "crawl" part of the variable makes sense, if this means that the variable is "crawling" around the tree... but what does the `p` refer to?

An example method:
void insert(struct TrieNode *root, string key) 
{ 
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;

```
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) 
{ 
    int index = key[i] - 'a'; 
    if (!pCrawl->children[index]) 
        pCrawl->children[index] = getNode(); 

    pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index]; 
} 

// mark last node as leaf 
pCrawl->isEndOfWord = true;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, in `C` language, a lower case `p` as a variable name prefix can be interpreted for `pointer`. This is the case in the example you provided.

This is in no case an explicit rule, just a naming convention followed here and there.